# How to connect .Net Webservice with local database

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, webserver

I have to connect my Database to an existing code in .NET. My Database is a MySql DB in PhpMyAdmin.

I am using `System.Data.SqlClient` in .NET and it seems like I cant get the connection String right for the connection function

```cs
private string _connetionString = @"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Testdb;"
SqlConnection _connection;

public DatabaseService()
{
  _connection = new SqlConnection(_connetionString);
}
```

Everytime I start my .Net-Service it needs a long time to and eventually the connection fails.

Comment: Try using that connection information and see if you can log-in to the db from another tool. That will help you out.

Comment: Ah damn, this is not the right information. This is the information from the other server. The problem is, that I am trying to connect some code that a colleague used on his machine, now im trying to use it on my machine with my own setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the right connection string syntax for MySQL. The sample you've posted looks to be for MSSQL. For MySQL you would need something like:

`"server=localhost;uid=username;pwd=password;database=Testdb"`

[MySQL API Reference for .NET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-connection-string.html)

Comment: Finally. This worked for me. I guess Stano Pet'kos would have worked somehow as well, but this works for me. Thanks a lot. I didn't think of checking the manual of MySQL as well. Smh...

Answer (score 2):

`SqlConnection` class (the whole namespace `System.Data.SqlClient`) is for connection to Microsoft SQL Server. You are using MySQL, so you need to use `System.Data.OleDb` namespace ([OleDbConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection)).

How connestion string for MySql look you can check here: https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/